# To move back the centre origin point to were the object is

Tags: modeling

Hi Please can you tell me how to move the 3D cursor and centre origin point back to were the object selected is please? 
I am selecting the landing feet and the X,Y and Z axis arrow is all the way to the right hand side please can you tell me how to fix it so it is situated relatively close to the object in this case the landing feet.

Thanks

Simon[image]

Comment: SHIFT +"C"  will return the cursor to the center of the scene. In "Object Mode" you can select "Set Origin" in the Tool Bar to the left.

Comment: hmm thsat did seem to work but did solve another issue i have been having so thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Select the object in question.

<kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter edit mode.

<kbd>A</kbd> to select all (You may have to hit it twice)

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> >> <kbd>U</kbd> To set the 3D Cursor to the average locational center of your selection.

<kbd>Tab</kbd> To exit edit mode.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> >> <kbd>T</kbd> To set the Origin to the new location of the 3D cursor.